# Problema al omitir la ejecucion de una tecla remapeada con libreria keyboard en python

Tags: python, macros, keyboard

Buenas tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un programa basico para remapear una tecla que abre una ventana con un QlineEdit para que el usuario introduzca la tecla que desea remapear y a continuacion debe pulsar el boton Record Macro para que se inicie la grabacion de todos los eventos del teclado. cuando el usuario quiere terminar la grabacion debe pulsar el boton save macro que detiene la grabacion y guarda todos los eventos en una variable llamada macro, la manera en la que remapeo la recla es pasandole con la linea
`keyboard.add_hotkey(key, lambda: keyboard.play(macro), suppress=True)`
El argumento de suppress=False se supone que sirve para que cuando si yo la macro se la asigno a la tecla 'a' y la pulso se suprima el evento de la tecla a y esta no se muestre.
El problema que tengo es que cuando ejecuto el codigo y le asigno a la letra 'a' por ejemplo los eventos de las teclas 'h' 'o' 'l' 'a' para que al pulsarla escriba 'hola', me escribe 'hoala' y no consigo que se omita la tecla.

el segundo problema que tengo es que cuando estoy grabando los eventos de las teclas y pulso la tecla de windows efectivamente la detecta pero en el momento que la voy a reproducir con la funcion play, esta no se reproduce como que se omite. alguien sabe una solucion para esto? eh probado a recrear la tecla con control+escape pero para grabaciones que intervenga la tecla de windows combinada con otra no funciona ejemplo windows+tabular.

el codigo del programa es este:

````
import keyboard
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton,
                               QLineEdit, QLabel, QVBoxLayout)
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

class MacroInterface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Macro Interface")

        # Create widgets
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.key_label = QLabel("Key to Map:")
        self.key_lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.record_button = NoSpacePushButton("Record Macro")
        self.record_button.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.save_button = NoSpacePushButton("Save Macro")
        self.save_button.setAutoDefault(False)

        # Add widgets to the layout
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.key_label)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.key_lineedit)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.record_button)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.save_button)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Connect signals
        self.record_button.clicked.connect(self.record_macro)
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_macro)

    def record_macro(self):
        print("grabando")
        keyboard.start_recording()

    def save_macro(self):
        print("guardado")
        key = self.key_lineedit.text()
        macro = keyboard.stop_recording()
        keyboard.add_hotkey(key, lambda: keyboard.play(macro), suppress=True)


class NoSpacePushButton(QPushButton):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() != Qt.Key_Space:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MacroInterface()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())```
````

Comment: Eh descubierto que el problema que tengo se debe a que efectivamente el supress = false omite la presion de la tecla pero no detiene que la tecla se suelte. pues añadi un escuchador de eventos en el sistema para ver que pasaba y descubri esto:Tecla presionada: h - Código: 'h'
Tecla soltada: 'h' - Código: 'h' 
Tecla presionada: o - Código: 'o'
Tecla soltada: 'o' - Código: 'o' 
Tecla soltada: 'a' - Código: 'a' 
Tecla presionada: l - Código: 'l'
Tecla soltada: 'l' - Código: 'l' 
Tecla presionada: a - Código: 'a'
Tecla soltada: 'a' - Código: 'a'

Comment: Mejor incorpora el comentario en tu respuesta, para una mejor comprensión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh descubierto que el problema que tengo se debe a que efectivamente el supress = false omite la presion de la tecla pero no detiene que la tecla se suelte. pues añadi un escuchador de eventos en el sistema para ver que pasaba y descubri esto:Tecla presionada: h - Código: 'h' Tecla soltada: 'h' - Código: 'h' Tecla presionada: o - Código: 'o' Tecla soltada: 'o' - Código: 'o' Tecla soltada: 'a' - Código: 'a' Tecla presionada: l - Código: 'l' Tecla soltada: 'l' - Código: 'l' Tecla presionada: a - Código: 'a' Tecla soltada: 'a' - Código: 'a'

Eh encontrado el fallo, en la llamada del metodo

`keyboard.add_hotkey(key, self.ejecucionMacro, suppress=Truetrigger_on_release=True)`

hay que agregar el siguiente parametro:
`keyboard.add_hotkey(key, self.ejecucionMacro, suppress=True, trigger_on_release=True)`

Comment: Acepta tu respuesta para cerrar la pregunta.